# How do I finish this switch statement?

Tags: javascript, parameters, switch-statement

How do I finish this switch statement? Not sure what switch params should be and what to return exactly without getting undefined as result..

I need to use my converter method to convert the different temperatures and in specific measures. Don't mind if my formula's aren't correct.

```
class Temperature {
constructor(measure, temperature) {
this.measure = measure;
this.temperature = temperature;
}

convert(variableForSwitchStatement) {
switch (variableForSwitchStatement) {
  case "C to F":
    return this.temperature * 1.8;
    break;

  case "C to K":
    return this.temperature + 273.15;
    break;

  case "F to C":
    return this.temperature - 32 * 0.5556;
    break;

  case "F to K":
    return ((this.temperature - 32) * 5) / 9 + 273.15;
    break;

  case "K to C":
    return this.temperature - 273.15;
    break;

  case "K to F":
    return 1.8 * (this.temperature - 273) + 32;
    break;
}
return variableForSwitchStatement;
}
}

var convertVar = "K to C";
const myTemperature = new Temperature(convertVar, 70);
console.log(myTemperature);
console.log(myTemperature.convert());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of variable to return, or put return in the `case` statements.
also use a variable to hold "K to C" as well as put a variable in the function convert(   **variable goes here**   )

````
class Temperature {
constructor(measure, temperature) {
this.measure = measure;
this.temperature = temperature;
}

convert(variableForSwitchStatement) {
switch (variableForSwitchStatement) {
  case "C to F":
    return this.temperature * 1.8;
    break;

  case "C to K":
    return this.temperature + 273.15;
    break;

  case "F to C":
    return this.temperature - 32 * 0.5556;
    break;

  case "F to K":
    return ((this.temperature - 32) * 5) / 9 + 273.15;
    break;

  case "K to C":
    return this.temperature - 273.15;
    break;

  case "K to F":
    return 1.8 * (this.temperature - 273) + 32;
    break;
// default statement to run if none of the cases are met
  default:
    return "Wrong Format"
  }
}
}


// K to C variable
var convertVar = "K to C"
const myTemperature = new Temperature(convertVar, 70);
console.log(myTemperature);
console.log(myTemperature.convert(convertVar));```
````

Comment: I did this, but outcome is always "Wrong format"..?

Comment: could you edit your original post with the updated code? it worked for me, so maybe it just wasn't put in correctly.

Comment: Saved as it is in my editor now

Comment: Oh shoot, I forgot the returns.

Comment: please check answer as the correct one, so it doesn't clutter stack overflow.